# unless blog has an article in liquid syntax

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to determine if a blog has an article or not.

```
{% unless blogs['events'].articles.empty? %}
    has article
{% endunless %}
```

Currently this returns to true whether I add an article or hide it.

my current source of reference: [what is true and false in liquid](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/what-is-true-and-false-in-liquid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`empty?`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/what-is-true-and-false-in-liquid#empty-drop) can be used to check if a collection, page or blog exists. If the blog exists and you want to know if it has any articles, try `blog.articles_count` or `blog.articles.size`.